# @ViewScoped managed bean gets destroyed when using h:inputFile

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, view-scope

I have problems using `h:inputFile` to upload Files in JSF 2.2.7 and Glassfish 4.1. I'm trying to get h:inputFile to work, but whenever I use the uploaded `Part` object from `h:inputFile`, the Backing bean gets destroyed and created again. Also the setter for the `Part` object is never called. I tried to isolate the problem by creating a page just with the upload (copied from a jsf example project), but the problem is still there. I also tried to use the Primefaces `p:fileUpload`, but the problem was still there. I also couldn't find any solutions by googling. Thanks for the help.

The JSF page `testMinUpload.xhtml` (removed `prependId="false"` from the form)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view>
    <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:messages/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="File:"/>
            <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{uploadController.file}"
                         validator="#{uploadController.validateFile}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:commandButton value="Upload File" action="#{uploadController.upload}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Upload File (Ajax)" action="#{uploadController.upload}">
            <f:ajax execute="file" render="@all"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:panelGrid id="content" columns="1">
            <h:outputText value="Content:"/>
            <h:inputTextarea readonly="true" value="#{uploadController.fileContent}"
                             rows="10" cols="100"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</html>
```

The Backing Bean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "uploadController")
@ViewScoped
public class TestFileUploadController implements Serializable {

    private Part file;
    private String fileContent;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("init() called");
    }

    public Part getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(Part file) {
        System.out.println("setFile() has been called");
        this.file = file;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the file contents of the file.
     */
    public void upload() {
        try {
            fileContent = new Scanner(file.getInputStream())
                    .useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Error handling
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validates the file.
     */
    public void validateFile(FacesContext ctx,
                             UIComponent comp,
                             Object value) {
        System.out.println("validateFile() called");
        List<FacesMessage> msgs = new ArrayList<FacesMessage>();
        Part file = (Part)value;
        if (file.getSize() > 1024) {
            msgs.add(new FacesMessage("file too big"));
        }
        if (!"text/plain".equals(file.getContentType())) {
            msgs.add(new FacesMessage("not a text file"));
        }
        if (!msgs.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ValidatorException(msgs);
        }
    }

    public String getFileContent() {
        return fileContent;
    }

    public void setFileContent(String fileContent) {
        this.fileContent = fileContent;
    }
}
```

`web.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
  <display-name>MyApp</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>testMinUpload.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

`faces-config.xml`

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>de</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>

    </application>

</faces-config>
```

`pom.xml` (updated to only include `javaee-web-api` as dependency)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>bar.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>myapp</name>
  <url>http://foo.bar</url>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>GNU Affero General Public License, Version 3</name>
      <url>https://gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.txt</url>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
          <port>8080</port>
        </configuration>

        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <app>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.war</app>
              <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
              <contextRoot>/${project.artifactId}</contextRoot>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
          <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
          <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

`glassfish-web.xml` (I alread tried to set the class-loader delegate to true, but this didn't fix the issue)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 4.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <class-loader delegate="false" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: Never use `prependId="false"` unless you absolutely understand its intent (hint: it's a leftover of a mistake in the ancient JSF 1.2 version). Get rid of it and retry.

Comment: Your POM also makes that the webapp includes Java EE based libraries which are already provided by the server itself. Fix that as well by marking the server-provided ones as `provided` and removing all duplicates (e.g. JSF and JavaMail are already covered by Java EE)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have removed `prependId="false"` and tried it again, the problem still persists (I'm gonna fix the pom.xml next)

Comment: I've updated the pom.xml. I wasn't quite sure which dependencies got provided by Glassfish (I checked the Glassfish 4.0 documentation, but I only could find a mention of Java EE 7 as provided package). So I set the Java EE related ones as you said to provided, and removed JSF and one JavaMail dependencies (the classes couldn't be loaded if I completly excluded the other one). The problem with h:inputFile is also still there after I've changed the pom.xml

Comment: Only `javaee-web-api` was been sufficient for the reproducer.

Comment: I've updated the `pom.xml`, so that only `javaee-web-api` is listed as dependency. I've also removed all classes / xhtml pages / config files which were not related to the problem. After cleaning these files, unfortunatly the problem still persists.

Comment: Just in case, I can't reproduce it with Mojarra 2.2.7-2.2.12 on Tomcat 8.